# iPhone - defining a conditional variable without a method

Tags: iphone

I have a file called myConstants.h that I use to put all the constants used by the app. This file is imported in any class that needs to access one of the variables.

I am building a universal app and I have variables that I need to have different values if they are running on iPad or iPhone.

I give you a generic example of what I mean.

In my main code I may have something like:

```
self.DEVICE = @"iphone";
self.IPAD = NO;

if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    self.DEVICE = @"ipad";
    self.IPAD = YES;
}
```

But this is define on the main code. If I need a class to use one of these two variables I need to construct complex methods to reference the main class and read the variables there.

My idea is to include this in `myConstants.h`.

But how can I do that if myConstants.h is just a plain file where every line is a `#define` entry without any method?

My idea is to have `DEVICE` and `IPAD` variables as globals for the entire app and make them available to any class by just `#import "myConstants.h"`.

Is this possible? How?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `#define` blocks will work in this case since those are interpreted at compile time. How would your compiler know which device the user is using?

I do something in one of my apps that uses [UIDevice extension](https://github.com/erica/uidevice-extension) to detect the device type at run time (in `if` statements).  This works fine.

Comment: that's it. Good idea. To have it as an extension of UIDevice. I am not using Erica Sadun extension, but rather designing a smaller one, as I don't need that much stuff. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the precompiler:

```
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
NSString *device_ = @"iphone"; 
#endif TARGET_OS_IPHONE
```

etc.

Then define your directives in the Build properties.

Comment: unfortunately that is useful just for compile time, not run time as I need. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Right, I was thinking more along the lines of a separate binary for each device "MyApp" and "MyApp HD for iPad".